# Questions exported to BBLearn are imported into individual pools, not one pool

Tags: r-exams

I'm using the latest version of R/Exams. When I export questions to Blackboard (`exams2blackboard`) in a ZIP file, then import the ZIP file into Blackboard in the "Test" page (to build a test) or the "Pool" page (to build a pool), each question is imported into its own individual pool, rather than all in a single pool. I must then create a new pool and manually copy each question from its own pool to the new pool, then delete the single-question pools one by one. It's very inconvenient and time-consuming. I don't know if this is a problem of Blackboard or an issue of R/Exams. Is there any way to export questions to a single pool in Blackboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of R/exams is designed for the case with dynamic exercises where you want to draw a (potentially large) number of random variations of each exercise. Hence, the random variations for one exercise form one "section" each of which is imported into a separate "pool" in Blackboard.

From your description I suspect that you have static questions and want to include each question exactly once within the same section/pool. This is possible by making the argument with the exercise `file`s not a vector or a list but a matrix, e.g.:

```
library("exams")
exm <- cbind(c("capitals.Rmd", "swisscapital.Rmd", "switzerland.Rmd"))
exm
##      [,1]              
## [1,] "capitals.Rmd"    
## [2,] "swisscapital.Rmd"
## [3,] "switzerland.Rmd" 
exams2blackboard(exm)
```

This creates a single section/pool with the three exercises in the order provided in the column of the matrix. It would also be possible to make a matrix with several columns that would then lead to separate sections.

*(Disclaimer: Lacking access to Blackboard, I couldn't test this myself, I have only inspected the XML code in the resulting ZIP which looked ok.)*